# How do I control access to "Public Groups I Own" in ECP in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

I need people to be able to edit the DLs that they own in OWA, but I don't want them to create new "Public Groups" (Distribution Lists).

How can I audit or control this granular access right?